# Pause recursive jquery scrolling text animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have written a jQuery animation that slides text upwards to create a vertical scrolling effect, then scrolls back to the original position and starts over.
The scrolling animation is working fine but I can't figure out how to get the animation to pause on hover, and resume on mouseout.
I'm trying to create a fallback for a CSS3 animation.

Here's a jsfiddle for what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/stlouisweb/5X3gZ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    function scroll(){
        var x = 0;
        var scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#scrollBox").delay(2000).animate({top:"-=30"}, 1000);
            if (++x === 2) {
                window.clearInterval(scrollInterval);
                $("#scrollBox").delay(2000).animate({top:"0px"}, 1000);
                scroll();
            }
        });
    };
    scroll();
});
```

Here is an updated fiddle showing how I thought this might work:
http://jsfiddle.net/stlouisweb/KD75a/1/

updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    function scroll(){
       $("#scrollBox").hover(function(){
          $("#scrollBox").stop();
          window.clearInterval(scrollInterval);
       });
        var x = 0;
        var scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
        $("#scrollBox").delay(2000).animate({top:"-=30"}, 1000);
            if (++x === 2) {
                window.clearInterval(scrollInterval);
                $("#scrollBox").delay(2000).animate({top:"0px"}, 1000);
                scroll();
            }
        }, 500);
    };
    scroll();
});
```

Comment: setInterval expects two parameters, a callback function and time interval. You have not supplied a time interval. Is this mistake only in your jsfiddle or also in your main code? Can you please fix the jsfiddle?

Comment: @msound, thanks for pointing that out.  The jsfiddle has been updated.

Comment: Look here: http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

Comment: Getting warmer, maybe?? http://jsfiddle.net/stlouisweb/5X3gZ/13/